# Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path XXX for model XXX

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a simple **User model** with a property called **bio** as follows:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema{
   bio:{
            type: String,
            max: 150,
            default: "Welcome to my linktree!"
        }
}
```

I have a function to **edit bio** as follows:

```
exports.editBio = async (req, res) => {

    User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {bio: req.body}, (err,data) => {
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }else{
            res.json(`Bio updated`)
        }
    })
}
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"bio\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "bio",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"bio\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer to my question :-**

The order of routes was previously:

```
router.put('/:id/edit/:linkId', isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, editLink)
router.put('/:id/edit/bio', isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, editBio)
```

I first swapped the order of these routes (after searching for somewhat similar problems on the internet, this seemed to work). New order of routes:

```
router.put('/:id/edit/bio', isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, editBio)
router.put('/:id/edit/:linkId', isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, editLink)
```

Then I edited my editBio function (code written below):

```
exports.editBio = async (req, res) => {

    var input = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    var fields = input.split('"');

    var newBio = fields[3];

    if(newBio.length > 150){
        return res.json(`Bio cannot be more than 150 characters`)
    }else{
        try {
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { bio: newBio });
            res.json(`Bio updated`)
        }catch (err) {
            res.json(err)
        }
    }

}
```